# How to use Provider in a particular view/screen

Tags: flutter, provider, state-management

I am using the Flutter provider package to manage all the states and separate the business logic from the UI part, and have all the API call present in the provider class that I need to call every time the user moves to that page.

But the issue is I don't want to hold the data even when the user moves to another screen that is the case when I declare provider in main.dart.

```
 class _HomeScreenAppState extends State<HomeScreenApp> {
    bool _isLoading;
    int counter = 0;
    String seller, user;

    @override
    void initState() {
     _isLoading = true;
     super.initState();
      }

    @override
    void didChangeDependencies() {
      super.didChangeDependencies();

     _fetchHomedetails();
    }

   Future<void> _fetchHomedetails() async {

     await Provider.of<HomeDetailProvider>(context, listen: false)
    .getEarnignStatus(context);}
  }
```

I have used ChangeNotifierProvider(create:(context) =>HomeProvider(),
builder:(context) => HomeScreen()
But if there is any dialog (bottomsheet, alertdialog) which is using HomeProvider, the dialog cannot access the HomeProvider data present on its parent widget.

Comment: So, you want the provider state to be in memory just for the current view? So you don't cache the data or the other way around and you want the provider to be alive longer to be a sort of cache?

Comment: Yes @croxx5f you are right

Comment: The first or the second option ? Sorry If I got them a little mixed up.